# Discord commands understanding

Tags: discord.py

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')



async def send_hi():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(942139956938276997)
    await channel.send('hello')

bot.loop.create_task(send_hi())
bot.run(token)
```

This is my first time working with commands, I usually work with events,can someone explain to me how commands work, and the function `bot.loop.create_task(send_hi())`

Answer (score 0):

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') # create a bot, which is a class inherit the Client class, with a command_prefix as "!"
# so you can use command like this: !your_command
# the "!" in "!your_command" is the command_prefix

async def send_hi(): # create a function named send_hi
    await bot.wait_until_ready() # wait for bot until ready
    channel = bot.get_channel(942139956938276997) # find a channel with that id and save it into "channel" variable
    await channel.send('hello') # send a message with "hello" as its content

bot.loop.create_task(send_hi()) # create a task for it to run at start
bot.run(token) # run the bot
```